# Формирование dataset'a для нейронной сети

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь освоить GAN, ( Конкурентно-состязательные нейронные сети) системы на Python. Я с толкнулся с проблемой формирования базы данных фотографий и изображений. Я хочу для тестов использовать собственный набор фотографий.(два архива .Jpg на 80000 и 3000 фотографий). Как мне это сделать? В образцах GAN нейронных сетей, часто используется запрос к институтам для скачивания и использования их предустановленных архивов. Это меня не устраивает.
Через какую библиотеку и команду мне загружать архив, и какие требования к архиву (формат)? Спасибо.